# how to dismiss an alert in React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am using an **Alert** , and  when i am navigating to previous screen on clicking of ok button this *alert is not dismissing*. 
  its showing up again in that back screen.

How i can stop this alert showing up again.

I am trying this code.

```
  showErrorAlert = () => {
   Alert.alert(
      CONSTANTS.SOME_ERROR_OCCURED,
      '',
      [{ text: 'OK', onPress: () => this.loggingOut() },],)
   };

 loggingOut = () => {
  console.log("coming here");
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following code, you can try adding **`{ cancelable: false }`**.

For more information go [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert.html)

```
showErrorAlert = () => {
   Alert.alert(
      CONSTANTS.SOME_ERROR_OCCURED,
      '',
      [{ text: 'OK', onPress: () => this.loggingOut() },],
       { cancelable: false })
   };

 loggingOut = () => {
  console.log("coming here");
  };
```

Comment: actually when i am clicking on ok button its dismissing and same time i am navigating to previous screen , but when i reach to the back screen , this alert pops up again.